# what's the difference between distcp hdfs and hftp,why distcp hdfs is effective?

Tags: hadoop, version

what's the difference between distcp hdfs  and  hftp,
why distcp hdfs  is effective?
we are copy HFDS files between two cluster of different version。

Answer (score 1):

distcp hftp should be used when the copying of the data between two clusters of different versions(different versions of hadoop). the command should be executed from the destination cluster, (more specifically, on TaskTrackers that can write to the destination cluster)

The source should be specified with hftp:///.

Comment: note: hftp is a read-only file system, which is why it can only be used on the source.  If you are copying between different versions of HDFS, you can't use the hdfs:// protocol because it is a binary protocol with no means to translate versions.